# Is it possible to store 5 days in memory dataframe in spark

Tags: apache-spark

we need to store 5 days stream data in memory using spark. After 5 days it should go to HDFS. Is it possible

Comment: Is it possible to store 5 days data in memory dataframe in spark

Comment: Check out spark streaming